# Why does Yarn fail with "no candidates found" errors?

Tags: yarnpkg, netlify, yarnpkg-v2, netlify-cli

For example, I'm trying to upgrade `netlify-cli` from 17.7.0 to 17.8.1 using `yarn upgrade-interactive` and the following error happens:

```
➤ YN0000: · Yarn 4.0.2
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0082: │ @netlify/zip-it-and-ship-it@npm:9.28.1: No candidates found
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 1s 602ms
➤ YN0000: · Failed with errors in 1s 617ms
```

and

```
➤ YN0000: · Yarn 4.0.2
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0082: │ @formkit/vue@npm:^1.3.0: No candidates found
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 22s 953ms
➤ YN0000: · Failed with errors in 22s 972ms
```

According to npmjs.com the package `@netlify/zip-it-and-ship-it` is available in the version requested:

[image]

I recently had this error multiple times with different packages.

What exactly does this error tell me and why does this happen?

Comment: Seems like a but in latest versions of yarn

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As [somebody pointed out on GitHub:](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/5989#issuecomment-1846996967)

Yarn caches the version history of the remote registry locally and relies on it, **instead of looking into the remote registry again** when a **version is not found locally**.

This is most likely a **bug** and can currently be solved by **deleting** the Yarn Berry Metadata Cache for NPM, which is located here on **Windows**

> C:\Users<your-user>\AppData\Local\Yarn\Berry\metadata\

or here

> ~/.yarn/berry/metadata/npm

**Edit**: You can also add a **preinstall hook** your **package.json** to clean the registry cache before every **yarn install** run

```
"scripts": {
   "preinstall": "rm -r ~/AppData/Local/Yarn/Berry/metadata/npm/"
   ...
}
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks

rm -rf ~/.yarn/berry/metadata/npm

Answer (score 5):

I had to use yarn 3.6.4 instead of 4.0.2 to make this error go away

`yarn set version 3.6.4`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by deleting *yarn.lock* and running *yarn* command again:

````
 ➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step 
 ➤ YN0082: │ npm-run-path@npm:^5.1.0: No candidates found 
 ➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 8s 78ms 
 ➤ YN0000: · Failed with errors in 8s 102ms ```
````

Comment: Deleting a project's yarn.lock can cause package versions to be unexpectedly changed and lead to other breaking issues

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other answers and they didn't work for me. I also tried everything I could think of: Reinstalling yarn, running `yarn cache clear`, deleting the entire ~/.yarn directory. What finally did it for me was deleting the `.yarn` file in the project repo. Posting in case anyone else runs into this.